# Trying to call function in DLL - translation from C to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, dll, translate

I have to access a DLL with Delphi, but have only the **.h** file. Most functions are translated and work flawless, but not this part:

```c
FUNCTION_PRE64 ULONG FUNCTION_PRE OpenModuleEx
(
    ULONG moduleID, 
    ULONG nr, 
    unsigned char *exbuffer, 
    ULONG open_options
);

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char address[256];
    ULONG timeout;
    ULONG portno;
    
    ULONG encryption_type;
    unsigned char encryption_password[32];
} DAPI_OPENMODULEEX_STRUCT;
```

My translation to Delphi is:

```pascal
function OpenModuleEx
(
    moduleID:Longint; 
    nr:Longint; 
    &buffer: exbuffer; 
    open_options: longint
): Longint; stdcall; external 'master.dll'

type exbuffer = packed record
    address : array of byte;
    timeout : Longint;
    portno : Longint;

    encryption_type : Longint;
    encryption_password : Array of byte;
end;
```

I fill the record and call the function:

```pascal
BinarySize := (Length('10.241.0.147') + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
SetLength(buffer.address, BinarySize);
Move('10.241.0.147'[1], buffer.address[0], BinarySize);
buffer.portno := 9912;
buffer.timeout := 5000;
buffer.encryption_type := 0;
BinarySize := (Length('') + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
SetLength(buffer.encryption_password, BinarySize);
Move(''[1], buffer.encryption_password[0], BinarySize);

lhandle := OpenModuleEx(42, 0, &buffer, 0 );
```

...but the returned handle is always `0`.

I'm no C expert and also no Delphi expert. My Delphi version is XE7. Who can help me to translate the struct to Delphi and how to fill it?

Comment: `array of Byte` is a *dynamic* array; it is a reference type. The record member is merely a pointer to a Delphi dynamic array heap object. You need 256 and 32 chars within the record itself: that is, you need *static* arrays.

Comment: You're most likely using the [DELIB software](https://www.deditec.de/media/manuals/en/manual_delib/index.html?dapiopenmoduleex.htm) and as per [the driver's **.h** file](https://www.deditec.de/media/zip/delib/delib-eth.zip) we also find the definitions of `DAPI_FUNCTION_PRE64` and `DAPI_FUNCTION_PRE` (which is `stdcall`). Interestingly the **.pas** file comments "_(not possible): DapiOpenModuleEx_" for reasons unknown to me. Are you sure you looked at everything been given to you?

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi record translation is incorrect. It should be:

```pascal
type 
  exbuffer = record
    address : Array [0..255] byte;
    timeout : Cardinal;
    portno : Cardinal;
    encryption_type : Cardinal;
    encryption_password : Array [0..31] byte;
  end;
```

The record should not be packed. `ULONG` maps to an unsigned 32 bit type. And the arrays must be fixed length arrays.

The function declaration is wrong too. It should be:

```
function OpenModuleEx(
    moduleID: Cardinal; 
    nr: Cardinal; 
    exbuffer: PByte; 
    open_options: Cardinal
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'master.dll';
```

It also may be that the function should be `cdecl` rather than `stdcall`, we cannot tell.

Comment: I'd just include `uses Windows` as it already defines the `type ULONG = Cardinal` and I'd be surprised if that would ever change.